# Use tasker to pass biometric authentication dialog (root)

Tags: root-access, fingerprint

### Main idea

I want to use a tasker action to authenticate a biometric prompt on a rooted device.

### Background

My use case is that I have a [Dangerous Things Apex implant](https://dangerousthings.com/product/apex-flex/) that I can securely scan to activate a tasker profile, meaning no security concerns compared to a regular NFC triggered task, and I have a rooted pixel 4a running LineageOS.

I got pretty far down the rabbit hole before I had to go to bed and got here: the [`onAuthenticationSucceeded`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt.java;bpv=1;bpt=1;l=482?q=BiometricPrompt%20onAuthenticationSucceeded&gsn=onAuthenticationSucceeded&gs=kythe%3A%2F%2Fandroid.googlesource.com%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject%3Flang%3Djava%3Fpath%3D%253Canonymous%2520android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricPrompt%25241%253E%2363f7efe14736bac2a7e92018e2ca4c181672ecb5bc7602981776dd7d981f76a5) method of a `BiometricPrompt` object.

### Ideas

- My inspiration was [lapwat's NfcScreenOffPie](https://github.com/lapwat/NfcScreenOffPie) who patched the nfc binary
- Or maybe we can emulate a second biometric sensor?

Comment: If the authentication prompt was requested because access to a key in AndroidKeyStore was requested then bypassing it will not be that simple because I don't think tasker has access to the Gatekeeper system which controls access and authentication (AFAIK Gatekeeper should run protected in TEE).